# How to make HttpWebRequest call using Claims Token?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity

I have two websites - ABC.com and XYZ.com. Both are in ASP.NEt MVC4. Both are configured as Relying parties against a common ACS (Secure Token Service) which is in turn delegating to Google.

First I make a call to ABC.com, once authenticated against google, I get Claims Identity in code by using Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity. Now I need to programmatically make HttpWebRequest/WebClient call to XYZ.com with this token and get response.

I am not able to find any tutorials or questions around this topic. Any insight is highly appreciated. How to make HttpWebRequest call using Claims Token?

Thanks,

Comment: I have a similar requirement and cannot find anything on it, please share any findings you may come across

Comment: @AdriaanDavel, I found an alternate way - http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/